# How to use the value of another variable in a GTM variable template?

Tags: google-tag-manager

It's probably very simple but I can't seem to find it.

Generally, if you create a custom variable and you need the value of another variable you put it in between double curly brackets. i.e.,

```
function() {
    var clickText = {{Click Text}};
    // do something with clickText
    return value;
}
```

How do I do this in a GTM variable template?

Comment: Frankly the best way would be to create a field in your template that allows variables as values (so the user can enter the Click Text variables themselves). Creating hidden dependencies somewhat defies the purpose of a template.

Comment: Ok, so I cannot retrieve any DOM information inside a template, correct?

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from `datalayer` you can use [custom template APIs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/api#copyfromdatalayer)

What you are looking for is `copyFromDataLayer` that "returns the value currently assigned to the given key in the data layer: The value found at the given key if it's a primitive type, function, or object literal, or undefined otherwise."

You can also find comprehensive guide [here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/custom-templates-guide-for-google-tag-manager/).

Comment: thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for the text of a clicked element. So a DOM element, but I understood it's not possible to get DOM elements in templates.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to enable built-in variable `Click Text`. And then you can use it as a value for your custom variables.

Comment: Yes, that's working fine, but I want to use it in a variable _template_.

Comment: @JeroenSwets I say about template. That exactly template do you mean?

Comment: I mean this: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving a correct answer here for there to be one.

Templates are still pretty limited. Despite claiming to be using ES6, they don't even allow regex. As a part of that limitation, they don't support referencing the variables like we used to in CJS vars.

Eike has a very good point there. It is viable to allow a manual overridal field in the template for cases when the default template behavior has to be adjusted based on a GTM variable, whether it's a dom scraping result or anything else.